# How to implement a Pkcs12 export in Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pkcs#12

I'm wondering how to implement the export statement below analogical in Bouncy Castle. I'm completely new to Bouncy Castle and couldn't find a easy-to-understand introduction to this topic in general or my issue specifically.
This is the openssl command I want to realize programmatically in java:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in bundle.crt -inkey private.key -out keystore.pkcs12 -name alias
```

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/joschi/cryptoworkshop-bouncycastle/blob/master/src/main/java/cwguide/JcePKCS12Example.java)

Comment: thanks for the quick reaction, I'll check this